# How to get Windows UWF available space in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, uwf

I'd like to run the following shell command in a C# program:

```
uwfmgr overlay get-availablespace
```

One simple solution would be call a cmd process like this:

```
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/user:Administrator /c uwfmgr overlay get-availablespace"
};

using (Process p = Process.Start(ps))
{
    output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

But is there a simple API to call in order to avoid to parse the output string of the process?
Another problem is that I have to call cmd with administrative rights.

UPDATE:
I try with WMI Api but with no success, here is my code:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
var uwfClass = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Overlay", null);
foreach (ManagementObject instance in uwfClass.GetInstances())
{
    var result = instance.InvokeMethod("AvailableSpace", null);
    break;
}
```

Comment: You can use WMI query to get that value as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfoverlay) and a side note you don't need administrative rights when you are just querying values.

Comment: Are you trying to supply the argument `/user:Administrator` to `cmd.exe`? it doesn't support such an argument, so you should read the help text returned when typing `cmd /?` into a command prompt window...

Comment: @Eldar yes WMI should be the right thing but I could not find any proper documentation about it... I try with the code posted in the answer but with no success (method not implemented)

Comment: Try `var result = instance.Item["AvailableSpace"]` since `AvailableSpace` is not a method but property.

Comment: @Eldar it works! Thank you. I added the full version of the code as a answer in order to help others.

Comment: Perhaps you will also find a suitable answer in my "experiment": https://github.com/cregx/uwf-dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code to obtain UWF `AvailableSpace` and `OverlayConsumption`.

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
var uwfClass = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Overlay", null);
foreach (ManagementObject instance in uwfClass.GetInstances())
{
    var availableSpace = Convert.ToInt32(instance.GetPropertyValue("AvailableSpace").ToString());
    var overlayConsumption = Convert.ToInt32(instance.GetPropertyValue("OverlayConsumption").ToString());
}
```